# Symmetrical encryption with hashing algorithm

Tags: encryption, hash

Can a file encrypted with a hashing algorithm (like SHA-256) be equally secure as a symmetrical algorithm (like AES)?

This is how it could be done using a password (this is the most simple example, please don't suggest optimizations, it's just the concept):

- Generate random looking binary data of the same length as the file contents, using `hash(password+counter+seed)`.
- XOR the file contents with the data generated above
- Store the result (the encrypted file) as the seed, followed by the XOR'ed data from above. The length of the encrypted file is (seed size + original file length).

The seed of course needs to be unique for every new file (like a GUID)

The question is not about how safe SHA-256 or AES is, or how safe a password is. Just assume we have a perfect hashing algorithm, a perfect symmetrical algorithm and a perfect password.

The question is why the encryption described above would be easier to break as the symmetrical algorithm.

Comment: To encrypt in counter mode with a hash function consider using HMAC, it is assumed to be a pseudo-random function hence the security analysis of CTR mode apply.

Comment: If you get specific about the primitive, sponge based constructions can be used to build aead schemes like' https://keccak.team/ketje.html

Comment: Some nags: ciphers require a key, not a password. To create a key from a password (*only* when a password is the only option) you'd use a PBKDF, regardless of the type of cipher. You use `data + SHA256(...)` after explaining that `+` is concatenation, but it is unclear what `data` is supposed to be. As it currently stands, the encryption routine is not well defined.

Comment: scrypt has been used as a stream cipher. What you're talking about is very inefficient and non-standard though and thus shouldn't be used over a symmetric algorithm.

Comment: If you make edits then please spell check. SHA-256 is the official name of the hash function. If such edits are made by high rep users, then please do not reverse them. On the content: a password that is completely secure is probably better called a *secret* (or, if it completely consists of randomized bits, a *key*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would the encryption (in the question) be easier to break than a symmetrical algorithm ?

The question uses it's hash algorithm to generate the keystream of a stream cipher. It's a symmetric encryption algorithm, about as safe as a standard symmetric encryption algorithm *if* that's directly using the password as key. But it's much less safe than a competently specified and implemented symmetric encryption algorithm, which should use a [memory-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-hard_function) password-based key derivation function like [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) to turn the password into a key.

For an ideal† hash, the only way to break the question's cipher is to guess the password. Proving this is a mere technicality. But the use of "password" implies something low-entropy, and the use of SHA-256 makes it a dream for [password cracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking) because it's well suited for GPUs, FPGAs, and ASICs. Passwords will be testable at extremely high speed except if the plaintext is essentially random.

---

† in the sense of being assimilable to a random oracle or to a public arbitrary member of a pseudo-random function family. The hash being collision-resistant or preimage-resistant is not enough for security. While SHA-256 is not designed for use as a random oracle or PRF, it's unbroken in these uses (when it's length extension property does not matter, which is the case at hand).

Comment: The suggested scheme is also *much* less efficient than say AES in CTR mode.

Comment: With AES in hardware and SHA-256 in software, for sure. Otherwise that's going to be tight, and I even doubt it in software that must be resistant to timing/side channel attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is this: counter + seed are not secret, only password is, so your scheme is only as secure as your password is.

Let's say your password is **random** and it uses lowercase, uppercase letters and digits. (62 possible characters in total).

For 128-bit security (like AES-128) your **random** password would have to be around 22 letters long.

For 192-bit security (like AES-192), it would have to be around 33 **random** letters long.

For 256-bit security (like AES-256), it would have to be around 44 **random** letters long.

If you use shorter passwords, your scheme would be easier to break than standard symmetric ciphers.

Comment: That's why I've put "assume we have a perfect password" in the question. 1 million bits of entropy if you want. This question is not about password security.